# drag and drop using jquery ui and html

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Hi friends i need some help here. I'm trying to create an animated drag and drop quiz like quizlet.com scatter game. you can see here by simply clicking start game, http://quizlet.com/35809118/scatter || in this link as you can see the element can be draggable and droppable if the both elements are not related together the dragged element revert back to random position. but I'm stuck with that random revert part. please check my working link

http://avinash.net23.net/drag/

and my working code is here:

css

```
.draggable{width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red}
.droppable{width:200px; height:200px; background-color:green}
p{font-size:22px}
```

jquery ui code

```
$(function() {
$('.draggable').draggable({revert:'valid'});
$( ".droppable" ).droppable({`enter code here`
drop: function( event, ui ) {

draggedone = $(ui.draggable).attr("title");
droppedone = $(this).attr("title");

if( draggedone == droppedone){
$(ui.draggable).fadeOut(1000);
$(this).fadeOut(1000);
}else{
$(ui.draggable).css({
'left':'50px'
});
}   
}
});
});
```

Comment: What will be your reverting position? Random empty table cell?

Comment: yes. it should be revert back to any of the random empty td.

Comment: If you could add the codes online and having the codes in JSFiddle will make it easier to find a solution. One more thing, there's is a reverting action but I cannot get the logic behind it.